# CMake globbing generated files

Tags: cmake, dependencies, code-generation, glob

I'm using `asn1c` in order to produce from one or more `.asn1` files a series of `.h` and `.c` files into a given folder.

These C files have no correspondence in names with the original `asn1` files.

These files must be linked together with mine in order to obtain a working executable. I'd love to be able to:

- Automatically generate the files in the build directory to avoid polluting the rest of the project (probably done with `add_custom_target`)
- Specify the dependency of my executable on those files, so that the `asn1c` executable is automatically run if the files are missing or if one of the `.asn1` files is updated.
- Automatically add ALL generated files to the compilation of my executable.

Since the generated files are not known in advance it's ok to just glob whatever the contents of the output directory of the `asn1c` command - as long as the directory is not empty I'm happy.

Answer (score 7):

CMake expects **complete list** of sources to be passed to `add_executable()`. That is, you cannot glob files generated at *build stage* - it would be too late.

You have several ways for handle generating source files without knowing their names in advance:

1. Generate files at *configuration stage* with `execute_process`. After that you may use `file(GLOB)` for collect source names and pass them to `add_executable()`:

   ```
   execute_process(COMMAND asn1c <list of .asn1 files>)
   file(GLOB generated_sources "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.c")
   add_executable(my_exe <list of normal sources> ${generated_sources})
   ```

   If input files for generation (`.asn1` in your case) are not intended to be changed in the future, this is the most simple approach which just works.

   If you intend to change input files and expect CMake to detect these changings and regenerate source, some more action should be taken. E.g., you may first copy input files into build directory with `configure_file(COPY_ONLY)`. In that case input files will be tracked, and CMake will rerun if they are changed:

   ```
   set(build_input_files) # Will be list of files copied into build tree
   foreach(input_file <list of .asn1 files>)
       # Extract name of the file for generate path of the file in the build tree
       get_filename_component(input_file_name ${input_file} NAME)
       # Path to the file created by copy
       set(build_input_file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${input_file_name})
       # Copy file
       configure_file(${input_file} ${build_input_file} COPY_ONLY)
       # Add name of created file into the list
       list(APPEND build_input_files ${build_input_file})
   endforeach()

   execute_process(COMMAND asn1c ${build_input_files})
   file(GLOB generated_sources "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.c")
   add_executable(my_exe <list of normal sources> ${generated_sources})
   ```
2. Parse input files for determine, which files would be created from them. Not sure whether it works with `.asn1`, but for some formats this works:

   ```
   set(input_files <list of .asn1 files>)
   execute_process(COMMAND <determine_output_files> ${input_files}
       OUTPUT_VARIABLE generated_sources)
   add_executable(my_exe <list of normal sources> ${generated_sources})
   add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${generated_sources}
       COMMAND asn1c ${input_files}
       DEPENDS ${input_files})
   ```

   In that case CMake will detect changes in input files (but in case of modification of **list** of generated source files you need to rerun `cmake` *manually*).

Comment: The real problem with this is that I also use `CMake` to actually build the `asn1c` executable, so I cannot run it before the build phase.

Comment: You may build `asn1c` as subproject at *configuration stage* with `execute_process()`. This looks like a good decision: no needs to defer build everything at *build stage*.